# Python Multiprocessing: run time increases with number of processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a multiprocessing task on all 4 processors of a core.  When I run just one of the four tasks that I actually want to run, the code takes about 3 seconds per 1000 iterations.  However, if I set it up to run all 4 processes the speed quadruples to 13 seconds per 1000 iterations.  I'm going to attach part of my code below.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  I've tried to do my own investigation and it doesn't seem to be a memory or cpu issue.  If I monitor as it runs with one task, one of the processors is active at 100% and only .8% of the memory is in use.  And when I run 4 tasks all 4 processors are active at 100% each with .8% of memory used.

Not sure why this is happening.  I've used the Multiprocessing task many times before and have never noticed a run time increase.  Anyways, here is my messy code:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from astropy.io import fits
import os
import time

def SmoothAllSpectra(ROOT, range_lo, range_hi):
    file_names = os.listdir(ROOT)
    for i in range(len(file_names)):
        file_names[i] = ROOT + file_names[i]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    for filename in pool.map(work, file_names[range_lo:range_hi]):          
        print filename+' complete'
    return ROOT

def work(filename):
    data = ImportSpectrum(filename)  ##data is a 2d numpy array
    smooth_data = SmoothSpectrum(data, 6900, h0=1)
    return filename

def SmoothSpectrum(data, max_wl, h0=1):
    wl_data = data[0]
    count_data = data[1]
    hi_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(wl_data - max_wl))
    smoothed = np.empty((2, len(wl_data[:hi_idx])))
    smoothed[0] = wl_data[:hi_idx]

    temp = np.exp(-.5 * np.power(smoothed[0,int(len(smoothed[0])/2.)] - smoothed[0], 2) / h0**2)
    idx = np.where(temp>1e-10)[0]
    window = np.ceil(len(idx)/2.)
    numer = np.zeros(len(smoothed[0]))
    denom = np.zeros(len(smoothed[0]))

    for i in range(len(numer)):
        K1 = np.zeros(len(numer))
        if (i-window >= 0) and (i+window <= len(smoothed[0])):
            K1[i-window:i+window] = np.exp(-.5 * np.power(smoothed[0,i] - smoothed[0,i-window:i+window], 2) / h0**2)

        elif i-window < 0:
            K1[:i+window] = np.exp(-.5 * np.power(smoothed[0,i] - smoothed[0,:i+window], 2) / h0**2)
        else:
            K1[i-window:] = np.exp(-.5 * np.power(smoothed[0,i] - smoothed[0,i-window:], 2) / h0**2)

        numer += count_data[i] * K1
        denom += K1

    smoothed[1] = numer / denom
    return smoothed
```

There's nothing fancy going on in the code, just smoothing some data.  I'm sure there are loads of ways to optimize this code, but I'm interested in why I'm seeing a computation time increase going from 1 task to 4 tasks.

Cheers!

Comment: Well let's back up two steps.  First, why do you think that parallelization is the *right* optimization?  Have you looked into [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) at all?  Second, what are you actually *doing* with your parallel processes?  What is the reason that throwing more processes at this particular operation is the right way to go?

Comment: I have a set of spectra that I need to smooth.  Each spectrum is independent of the others.  It takes a while (about 10 minutes) to smooth one spectrum, so I am sending one spectrum to each processor for smoothing.  Therefore, I am smoothing 4 at a time on each core, and I am also submitting the job to multiple cores.  I haven't looked at cProfile.  But I think parallelization is the way to go.